# What exactly does the binary "deplister.exe" do in C:\PHP?

Tags: windows, php

The Windows version of PHP has a file called "deplister.exe" in it. When I run it, it outputs nothing at all, and it doesn't respond to "-h" or anything.

What exactly is the purpose of this file? I've tried searching online and found nothing but virus result.

Answer (score 4):

It's a dependency lister. If you provide it with the name of a DLL it will show you what that DLL has a dependency on. For example:

```
deplister libpq.dll
```

May show something like this (using PHP 7.4.4):

> libssl-1_1-x64.dll,OK libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll,OK Secur32.dll,OK
>
> WS2_32.dll,OK WLDAP32.dll,OK KERNEL32.dll,OK ADVAPI32.dll,OK
>
> SHELL32.dll,OK VCRUNTIME140.dll,OK
>
> api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND
>
> api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll,NOTFOUND